# Capture all packets sent from and to application

Tags: c#, c++, sockets, winapi, packets

I would like to capture all packets sent and received by application. Then edit some of them before they reach their destination (and delay them in some cases).

What is the best way to "inject" in that path of packets?

I want to do it with C++ and Windows api. (Maybe C# with pInvoke).

Answer (score 0):

There'd no quick solution. You'll need a driver. Here's an example:
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowshardware/NDISLWFSYS-Sample-NDIS-60-42b76875

Comment: Only driver? I know I can hook send and recvfrom in process. But just in that one process I'm working with I can't do it. There has to be a way without driver.

Comment: @Hooch Why can't you do the hooking in that process?